# Can I send static image to Server through HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm thinking about a plugin that can upload whatever user see in his page,
let's talk about the image
I don't wanna to format the img.src ,send to the server and let the server side to fetch the img
Instead,I wanna to get the img's raw data,maybe base64 and then use xmlhttprequest(level2)
to send the raw data
Any One get some ideas of it?Thanks :)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to load a page from a webserver and send the images back to the server again via JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think JS can do screenshots (security issue). I can't even imagine a use case for this though, what is the purpose of doing this? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Thor84no: "Report a problem with this page" like G+ does. People can select the area of the site or multiple areas that are related to the issue.

Comment: When it comes to that I'd prefer getting the DOM elements they select and chucking their contents to the server rather than a screenshot as that will allow you to both see what is causing it to look wrong AND replicate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to take a look at this: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery I would do this:

```
  var canvasData = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL('image/png');
  canvasData.replace('data:image\/png;base64', '');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/save',
    data: 'rawData='+canvasData,
    success: function(){
      // hoorayy!
    }
  });
```

But first you need to draw your image to Canvas. Like that:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = 'image.jpg';

    imgObj.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
  }
```

[Here](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/) you can read more on saving canvas with toDataURL